# Can't an LSTM count the number of cycles of the input?

Tags: lstm, trend, recurrent-neural-network

Can an LSTM count number of cycles? Or, equivalently predict a linear trend from a sinusoidal input?

I have tried to train an LSTM network on a problem that I supposed would be easy for it.

The dataset is composed of just one sequence. The input is composed of 100 cycles of two sinusoid shifted  by $\pi/2$, discretized at 100 points per cycle:

$x(t) = [\cos(2 \pi t/100), \sin(2 \pi t/100)]; t = 0, 1, 2, ..., 10000$.

The output I would like to fit is a linear function of $t$:

$y(t) = t/10000; t = 0, 1, 2, ..., 10000$.

That is, $y$ counts the number of cycles (divided by 100) of the input sequence $x$. The best result I could obtain using  during the train, using the mean square error as loss function, predicts an output $\hat{y}$ which is a sinusoid of small amplitude oscillating around 0.5 (which is the average of $y(t)$).

Is an LSTM network really not able to model this relationship between $x$ and $y$? Is any other recurrent neural network able of doing so?

Comment: What is the result of your experiment?

Comment: @LernerZhang, the result was a sinusoid of small amplitude oscillating around 0.5 (which is the average of y(t)).

Comment: What is your loss function?

Comment: @LernerZhang, added to the question "using the mean square error as loss function". Thank you.

Comment: Does this task work if you use a smaller-length sequence first? 10000-length sequences are very difficult for an LSTM.

Comment: @tchainzzz, this task did work after I changed to a smaller-length sequence. Thank you.